# Why wasn't this character at the trial?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In S06E10, towards the end we see Cersei wineboarding Septa Unella. They talked, she screamed.

But why wasn't Septa Unella at the temple during the trial? You'd think her high position in the Faith as well as the sadistic side would guarantee her presence at a trial.

Comment: Septas were not a part of the tribunal I believe. Also, Wasn't Unella staying at Red Keep with Margaery? Cersei could have abducted her inside the Red Keep before the trial

Answer (score 8):

It is not explained or shown in the episode, but one could speculate that Cersei snatched her before she had a chance to leave to the Sept of Baelor.

Cersei had a special hate towards Septa Unella and she wanted her to suffer more then those she was about to kill with wildfire, that is a clear fact.

Septa Unella was originally keeping a eye on Queen Margaery, so one can ask why Margaery did not notice her pitbull watchdog disappearing. Unfortunately there is no real answer to that question.

Comment: I simply assumed that once Marge no longer needed supervision and the cells were no longer in use, as the toughest septa, she was re-assigned to supervising Cersei in the red keep.

Comment: Cells are in use because of Loras (he was not set free yet). Only Bran is able to give the answers

Comment: I don't believe Margery would mind Unella going missing, let alone point out to someone that her watchdog is gone.